# Is there a way to resolve statically this circular dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, graphql, python-attrs

I have some python classes that relate to one another, they attempt to mimic a graphql schema (The schema itself is not relevant, I post here the base case to reproduce the issue).

The GraphQL schema looks like this:

```
type User {
  name: String
  orders: [Order]
}

type Order {
  key: String
  user: User
}
```

From a schema-design point of view, there is nothing wrong with this schema, it's a valid one and I already have a database running with this relationships (it just means: An user may have several orders, an order may have only one user that created it).

It's in the python side of things that things get a little messy.

I would expect the following code to work:

file: models/Model.py

```py
import attr

@attr.s
class Model():
  pass # Model internal workings not relevant to the example
```

file: models/User.py

```py
from typing import List
import attr
from . import Model

@attr.s
class User(Model):
  name: str = 'Name'
  orders: List[Order] = attr.ib(factory=list)
```

file: models/Order.py

```py
import attr
from . import Model

@attr.s
class Order(Model):
  key: str = 'abc'
  user: User = attr.ib(factory=User)
```

then I can do things like this:

file: **main**.py

```py
import models as m
user = m.User.query(name='John', with='orders')
user.name # "John"
user.orders # [m.Order(key='1'), m.Order(key='2'), m.Order(key='3')...]
order = m.Order.query(key='1', with='user')
order.key # "1"
order.user # m.User(name="John")
```

This code does not work due to the circular dependency (User needing Order type to be defined earlier, and Order requiring User).

The workaround I found was late-importing the models using the importlib:

```
# current solution:
# using the importlib to import dynamically

from typing import List
import attr
from helpers import convert_to, list_convert_to, 

# Note: "convert_to" receives a class name and returns a function to instantiate it dinamically

@attr.s
class Model():
  pass

@attr.s
class User(Model):
  name: str = 'Name'
  orders: List[Model] = attr.ib(factory=list_convert_to('Order'))

@attr.s
class Order(Model):
  key: str = 'abc'
  user: Model = attr.ib(factory=list_convert_to('User'))
```

this solution works, but loses the ability to know beforehand the types of the fields, and I think it is slower when building complex relations (hundreds of items with Objects several levels deep).

This is why i am looking for better ways to solve this problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 3.7 or later, the following line will make it work:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

It also allows you to refer to a class while defining it. E.g.

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls) -> C:
        ...
```

works now.

If your classes are defined in multiple files and you get a circular dependency due to that, you can guard the imports using

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

# ...

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from module import User
```

Comment: Even without `annotations`, you can simply use a string `'C'` in place of the reference `C`. (That's pretty  much all `annotations` does: defer evaluation of the expression and simply save it as a string.)

Comment: @hynek, This seems to work fine if classes are defined in the same file, but still fails when every class is in its own File: `<Model>.py`. Is there a way around this?

Every file has its own `from __future__ import annotations` on the top of the file

Comment: @chepner I need the concrete type, not a string, because I use it later to perform type-casting (I'm not sure I follow your suggestion)

Comment: @BarucAlmaguer I have updated the answer: there is a construct for that but it clashes with your requirement for concrete classes. This is where Python's tack-on of types clashes with how imports works unfortunately.

Comment: @hynek When you say: _"...but it clashes with your requirement for concrete classes"_ what do you mean?. TYPE_CHECKING won't work with this example? if so, is there a way to refactor those classes to allow this type of guarded import or would you suggest to include all the models in the same file? (The model files are built with a script, so it would be easy to refactor if that's the best practice)

Comment: I updated the question to show the models are in different files

Comment: This is not really a typing question anymore: you can’t have cyclic imports between files period. The guard allows you to use those types for typing, but you can’t use them to instantiate them.  Neither should you tho, cf Dependency Inversion Principle.